# Google Map markers are not displayed (lat, lng values and other information is loaded from an xml file)

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, google-maps

I am working on the example given here:- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps
I am at the point "Loading xml file". I have linked database with php to form xml file (File.xml) of the data given but I don't know why is it not working. I have tried many other examples. But could not just figure out the part "how to load xml file" as no code worked and there's no error in the console.

```
<script>
              var customLabel = {
            restaurant: {
              label: 'R'
            },
            bar: {
              label: 'B'
            }
          };

        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.863276, 151.207977),
          zoom: 12
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('File.xml', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to copy the last line of the downloadUrl function:     request.send(null);

Comment: Yead I did both the ways. My web browser just cached the result of my non-working code beforehand.
I just copy pasted it again and it worked

Comment: Thanks @nicolastorre:)